# for loop - in last Iteration , Terms were not working properly

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I can not understand why in the last iteration 12 is replacing 14. If conditions have a big organ max current array only then substitute another max remains the same.

Possible explanation please?

This process makes the current loop:

```
max: 1 min: 1
max: 3 min: 1
max: 9 min: 1
max: 10 min: 1
max: 12 min: 1
max: 14 min: 1
max: 12 min: 1
```

The loop:

```
int result=0;
    int arr[] = { 1, 3, 9,10,12,14,12 };

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int max=arr[0];
        int min=arr[0];
        if(arr[i]>max){
            max=arr[i];

    }
        else if(arr[i]<min){
            min=arr[i];

        }
                System.out.println("max: " + max + " min: "+min);

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The initialization of `max` and `min`

```
    int max=arr[0];
    int min=arr[0];
```

should be prior to the loop. Otherwise, you are overwriting these variables in each iteration of the loop.

```
int max=arr[0];
int min=arr[0];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]>max){
        max=arr[i];
    } else if (arr[i]<min) {
        min=arr[i];
    }
    System.out.println("max: " + max + " min: "+min);
}
```

This code assumes the array is not empty.